# How to edit comment template and add type or function comment in JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, templates, comments, intellij-idea

In JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA, I would like to edit comment which is like

```
/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.<br/>
 * User: ${USER}<br/>
 * Date: ${DATE}<br/>
 * Time: ${TIME}<br/>
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
```

and generate comment for a type like

```
public class MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
```

or a function like

```
protected  void checkUsbKeyID(UserObj user,String usbKeyID)
```

Answer (score 55):

Type comments you can edit in menu `File -> Settings -> File Templates`.
Then you look to tab `Includes` and edit entry `File Header`

[image]

Method comments isn't possible to edit, I think.

Answer (score 13):

To change the specific template for Classes, edit the **Class** template.

*Example menu locations* (should be broadly similar on other platforms/versions)

**IntelliJ 2016, Mac**

> Preferences > Editor > File and Code Templates > Files tab > Class item

**IntelliJ 14.x, Mac**

> Preferences > Editor > File and Code Templates > Templates tab > Class item

It looks like this

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
#parse("File Header.java")
public class ${NAME} {
}
```

The link to the sub-template which generates the comments is `#parse("File Header.java")` on the second line.

You can remove that and put a custom comment template for Classes inline here.

**or**

You can edit the **File Header** template under the **includes** tab, which is also used by other things, and edit that